# Checking out one external in subversion, after --ignore-externals

Tags: svn, svn-externals

So let's say I have a code checkout that I used `--ignore-externals` on originally.  One of the directories has several large externals in it.

*After* having checked out my sparse copy, is there a way to retrieve just one of those externals?  As far as I can tell, all I can do is `svn up .` and retrieve all the externals at once.  `--depth` doesn't seem to work in this case, nor does `svn up external_dir/` since it doesn't exist yet.  I even tried faking it with `mkdir external_dir/; svn up external_dir/`, although I didn't really expect that one to work.

So, is it possible to retrieve/update only one external, rather than everything in the directory, if it was originally ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's what I ended up doing:  Alter the externals so only the one I want is listed, update, and revert.

```
svn propset svn:externals "$(svn propget svn:externals . | grep external_foo)" .
svn up .
svn revert .
```

Don't forget the various periods that specify "current directory".